# Change database schema of entitymanager during runtime based on logged in user

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I have read many questions and answers about dynamic implementation of `EntityManager` with different schemas. I found also a solution using alter database session to set current schema (see below). 
`ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA= "SCHEMA_NAME"`

As the number of users using the application increases, this isn't a suitable way of routing anymore. Also, it would change to `EntityManager` on every time a new user login. The situation is as follows

```
1 database server
many schemas on that server, every user has their own schema.
I only need to change the schema name during runtime the schema name is retainable by logged in user
```

I'm using Spring with Hibernate 4.0 and Spring data JPA

I can't find a way to change the schema completely dynamically. Does someone know how to do it in spring?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation